# string id generator

Tags: jpa

what's the easiest way to implement a string id in jpa ?
So far what I have is

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
```

and what I'd like to have is something like

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private String id;
```

but if I use it like this, I get 'this id generator generates long, integer, short'.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create the UUID from Java like this:

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Or if your JPA supports it, like Hibernate does, you can use:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
private String myId;
```

[Checkout this blogpost for details.](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/06/03/jpa-implementation-patterns-using-uuids-as-primary-keys/)

If you google for "JPA UUID" there are many alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using EclipseLink, you can use the @UuidGenerator,

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_uuidgenerator.htm#CFAFIIFC

You should also be able to convert a sequence integer to a string if desired.