# How to add attribute to a mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using `@MappedSuperclass` annotation in the following way:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Recipient {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    //GET, SET
}
```

I also have two entity classe, inherited from one:

```
public class Player extends Recipient{
    //FIELD, GET, SET
}
```

and

```
public class Partner extends Recipient{
    //FIELD, GET, SET
}
```

The thing is `private int id` filed in the `class Player` has an additional attribute:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
```

Is it possible to specify that? We can override attribute with annotation `@AttributeOverride`, but what about to add one?

Comment: You can't. I tried to solve a similar problem here: [How to create a generic entity model class that supports generic id including auto generated ids?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26109041/1065197). At the end, I have different classes for id support and my classes have to extend one or another since Java doesn't allow multiple class inheritance.